# Link a mapa de google en HTML

Tags: html, google-maps

tengo la siguiente consulta; yo he visto en muchos lugares que la gente incluye en sus sitios web mapas de google con algun punto marcado en el mapa.
Bueno, yo en lugar de esto, necesito hacer un link en html (con una etiqueta  por ejemplo), que cuando el usuario lo clickee, lo lleve a otra pestaña y le abra google maps con la ubicacion que yo quiera seleccionada.

Como verán, es un poco rebuscada la inquietud, estimo que por eso no pude haya solucion buscando en la web.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Hola! No creo que sea muy difícil :) Te sugiero hacerlo a la inversa: ve a Google Maps, elige un punto, dale a compartir, y voilà, ya tienes el link: sólo debes colocar las coordenadas que necesitas (que de hecho las puedes obtener del mismo maps....).

Comment: Claro, eso intenté, y me funciona solo la parte de que me muestra bien la ubicacion en el mapa. Pero no muestra el punto marcado en el mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te abra otra ventana agrega el atributo `target="_blank"`

```html
<label>Con Vínculo </label>
<a href="https://www.google.com.gt/maps/place/Parqueo+AGEXPORT/@14.5824309,-90.5210567,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x3c37246f94a217c5!8m2!3d14.5842843!4d-90.5234009" target="_blank">Vínculo</a>


<label>Incrustado en tu sitio </label>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d15445.167938361248!2d-90.52105674999999!3d14.582430949999997!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x3c37246f94a217c5!2sParqueo+AGEXPORT!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sgt!4v1521136049859" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Si necesitas cambiar las coordenadas, según el ejemplo anterior, debes sustituir los siguientes parámetros:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com.gt/maps/@14.5824309,-90.5210567,15z" target="_blank">Original</a>
```

Con los parámetros que debes sustituir, imaginando que es `php` ya que no especificas, quedaría así:

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com.gt/maps/@<?php echo $valor1 ?>,<?php echo $valor2 ?>,15z" target="_blank">Parametrizado</a>
```

Comment: Claro, entiendo. Yo necesito como mancionas correctamente vos a primer forma. Solo que ese es un link estático, yo necesitaria que segun una latitud y logitud que tengo almacenados en base de datos, me abra el mapa donde debe ser. Me explico?

Comment: @AlejandroZbrun ya edite la respuesta pasando los parámetros con **php** para que te sirva de referencia. En tu próxima pregunta puedes estructurarla mejor, dale un vistazo al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y para estructurar una buena preguntar visita [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Listo, genial, eso funciona y soluciona mi consulta. Ahora, cuando abre la pestaña efectivamente esta ubicado el mapa correctamente, pero no esta el punto rojo o marcador. Alguna idea sobre como hacer que siga apareciendo el marcador en el mapa?

Comment: @AlejandroZbrun Para que aparezca el punto rojo entonces debes pasar como parámetro el `/place/<?php echo place   ?>/` Obviamente debes estar seguro que en las coordenadas que mandas existe un place con ese nombre.

Comment: probé con esto y no me funcionó: https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/@<?php echo $latitud ?>,<?php echo $longitud ?>,15z/place/<?php echo $nombre_ciudad ?>/

Comment: es decir, me ubica bien el mapa, pero no me marca el punto rojo :S

Comment: @AlejandroZbrun Comprendo, te quedo mal, estoy viendo que el último parámetro **data** no podemos controlarlo, gracias a eso que le pasas te marca el punto rojo